# How an instance is randomly unable to resolve hostname?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Elastic Beanstalk service.

In that service the code connects to an external service resides in IDC.

Let's say the address is `http://some.mydomain.com/aaa`.

In my EB instance I see this.

```
$ curl -v "http://some.mydomain.com/aaa"
...OK

$ curl -v "http://some.mydomain.com/aaa"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: some.mydomain.com
```

How can this happen? What should I do?